# Regular expression in PHP fgetcsv

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match, fgetcsv

I have a cycle in my code where I want to extract only the first, fifth and sixth number from an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 12403;644;20;46;5;285;;;; )
```

I am currently trying to use regular expressions to extract those numbers (in this case I need to get 12403, 5 and 285).

```
$contents = fgetcsv($handle);
preg_match('/^(\d+);\d+;\d+;\d+;(\d+);(\d+);*.$/', $contents, $match);
echo "first capture group: " . $match[0] . "\nsecond capture group: " . $match[1] . "\nthird capture group: " . $match[2];
```

This prints out empty variables. Why? Can you please help?

Comment: Why don't you just specify `;` as the CSV delimiter? Then you can use `$contents[0]`, `$contents[4]`, etc.

Comment: Nice, that looks better :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$contents is an array, `preg_match` needs a string. So it should be:

```
preg_match('/^(\d+);\d+;\d+;\d+;(\d+);(\d+);*.$/', $contents[0], $match);
```

Then, capture groups start at `1`; `$match[0]` is the match for the entire regexp. So it should be:

```
echo "first capture group: " . $match[1] . "\nsecond capture group: " . $match[2] . "\nthird capture group: " . $match[3];
```

But a simpler solution would be to use the correct delimiter when calling `fgetcsv()`, so it will split the line for you -- that's the whole point of using `fgetcsv()` instead of `fgets()`.

```
$contents = fgetcsv($handle, ';');
echo "first capture group: " . $contents[0] . "\nsecond capture group: " . $contents[4] . "\nthird capture group: " . $contents[5];
```